# Payment module redirect to payment website url in magento2

Tags: magento2, payment, magento-2.0

How to create payment module in Magento 2 with redirection to a payment gateway website?

Answer (score 6):

To create payment module i used below payment module creator:

http://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-payment-module-creator

Then, for redirection, below is code replaced in 
`app\code\YOUR_NAME_SPACE\Testpayment\view\frontend\web\js\view\payment\method-renderer\testpayment-method.js`

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*browser:true*/
/*global define*/
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
    'mage/url',
],
function (
    $,
    Component,
    placeOrderAction,
    selectPaymentMethodAction,
    customer,
    checkoutData,
    additionalValidators,
    url) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'YOUR_NAME_SPACE_Testpayment/payment/testpayment'
            },
            placeOrder: function (data, event) {
                if (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                var self = this,
                    placeOrder,
                    emailValidationResult = customer.isLoggedIn(),
                    loginFormSelector = 'form[data-role=email-with-possible-login]';
                if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                    $(loginFormSelector).validation();
                    emailValidationResult = Boolean($(loginFormSelector + ' input[name=username]').valid());
                }
                if (emailValidationResult && this.validate() && additionalValidators.validate()) {
                    this.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(false);
                    placeOrder = placeOrderAction(this.getData(), false, this.messageContainer);

                    $.when(placeOrder).fail(function () {
                        self.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(true);
                    }).done(this.afterPlaceOrder.bind(this));
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            },

            selectPaymentMethod: function() {
                selectPaymentMethodAction(this.getData());
                checkoutData.setSelectedPaymentMethod(this.item.method);
                return true;
            },

            afterPlaceOrder: function () {
                window.location.replace(url.build('mymodule/standard/redirect/'));
            },
            /** Returns send check to info */
            getMailingAddress: function() {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
            }


        });
    }
);
```

Last step and **most important**, run

- **bin\magento setup:upgrade** to install the module
- **bin\magento sampledata:deploy** to move all `js` and `css` file to `pub/static` folder because in few case payment `js` and template files is not moved to `pub/static` folder. In that case move this files, else it will not visible in checkout page.

Comment: Hi Pradeep, I tried above but it is not redirecting at all, can you please let me know how you have done it or can you share your code which you have implemented.

Comment: Hi Pradeep, command to deploy static content is bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: hi Pradeep, given link is not working.Any help to get the module