# Error "Payment model name is not provided in config" when having config in payment section

Tags: magento2, extensions, payment-methods, development

I have an extension that has some config fields in the `payment` section. The extension does **not** supply a payment method, I just want to have the settings in the *Payment Methods* section.

`module.xml`:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Example_MyExtension" setup_version="0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

The `system.xml`looks like this:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
  <system>
    <section id="payment">
      <group id="myextension" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="99" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>MyExtension</label>
        <field id="activate_export" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
          <label>Export Orders</label>
          <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
        </field>
      </group>
    </section>
  </system>
</config>
```

And thats what it looks like:
[image: MyExtension]

So everything's fine until now. Now I want to have a default value, so I create `config.xml`.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
  <default>
    <payment>
      <myextension>
        <activate_export>1</activate_export>
      </myextension>
    </payment>
  </default>
</config>
```

When I try to open the configuration, I see nothing and get the following error in `system.log`:

> Payment model name is not provided in config!

The error is thrown in `/vendor/magento/module-payment/Helper/Data.php` in `getMethodInstance()`. As far as I can tell, the code tries to load a payment method named `myextension` and fails.

When I place the configuration under section `sales`, everything works as expected.

Questions:

1. Is this a bug?
2. If not, is it not only allowed to put configuration for payment modules in `payment`?

Comment: I'm facing same error...how to solve it @Manuel

Comment: @PriyaM did you try to create a payment.xml or setting a title in etc/config.xml (see answers)?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <fee_config>    
                <fee_enabled>1</fee_enabled> 
                <fee_title>codfee</fee_title>                            
            </fee_config>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>

Comment: Yes.....this is my config.xml file.but still not getting config values

Comment: Hi @ManuelM Did you get the solution for this? I am struggling

Comment: I disagree with all answer because magento assumes that any setting under `payment` must be connected to a payment module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this problem when I removed my module and reinstall again. Just solved it a few second ago.
You need to create a payment.xml since you are creating a payment module.

By the way the payment.xml can be created using CedCommerce payment module creator. I think the link has been shared by the savior above.

```
<methods>
    <method name="(here type in your module name in lower case)">
        <allow_multiple_address>0</allow_multiple_address>
    </method>

</methods>
```

Put this payment.xml in your module etc directory and it should able to be solved. You may use the method name to register a configprovider in model if you wish.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. See my own answer for details.

Comment: I'm facing same error...but it not works  for me.how to solve it

Answer (score 10):

I disagree with the accepted answer. I found myself in a similar situation as OP and made my own experiments to get rid of this error, and what solved it for me was setting a title in `etc/config.xml`.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <my-method>
                <title>My method</title>   <!-- backend will show errors if TITLE isn't set to a value here -->

                <merchant_id backend_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted" />
                <security_key backend_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted" />
            </my-method>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

The accepted answer talk about `etc/payment.xml` but that made no difference for me (the backend works even when that file does not exist).

Comment: I had the same issue but I did have a title in config.xml, so I don't think the title is related. However I did not have the payment.xml entry mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide `<model>` node in your `config.xml` file. See example from Authorize.net module:

```
<default>
        <payment>
            <authorizenet_directpost>
                ...
                <model>Magento\Authorizenet\Model\Directpost</model>
                ...
            </authorizenet_directpost>
        </payment>
    </default>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

to create payment module with 3ed party api website follow the below post if it helps accept the answer which help others 
[Payment module redirect to payment website url in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94480/payment-module-redirect-to-payment-website-url-in-magento2)

Comment: I don't want to build a full payment module, see question. Besides, the link in the linked question (http://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-payment-module-creator) does not work for me (ClodFlare says "
Error 1000 DNS points to prohibited IP")

Answer (score 0):

As of Magento 2.3 and 2.4, the only place this message is created is within `vendor/magento/module-payment/Helper/Data.php` as follows:

```php
    public function getMethodInstance($code)
    {
        $class = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $this->getMethodModelConfigName($code),
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );

        if (!$class) {
            throw new \UnexpectedValueException('Payment model name is not provided in config!');
        }

        return $this->_methodFactory->create($class);
    }
```

And `getMethodModelConfigName` is declared just before this one:

```php
    protected function getMethodModelConfigName($code)
    {
        return sprintf('%s/%s/model', self::XML_PATH_PAYMENT_METHODS, $code);
    }
```

Which means both [@Bery](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/224995/555)'s and [@Antoine](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/316538/555)'s  responses are correct.

**However,** for those like me, **you may have been fooled by opcache**. Opcache caches the things when in use and the model may not exist after you've installed your module because Magento is still reading it from the cache generated prior to that.

That said, the solution would be:

1. Make sure you've cleaned your opcache (or restart php-fpm and nginx/apache)
2. Make sure your payment module have defined the model as stated by @Bery
3. Do `bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

Answer (score 0):

1.I got the Same error while adding a custom payment method in the checkout page. I resolved the error by following:

a.Make sure the payment method code is added same as the title for the payment method.

b.Make sure in the config.xml,the title is added the same as payment method code.