# Magento 2.0 does getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl work?

Tags: payment-methods, custom, payment-gateway, third-party-module

I am trying to convert an existing custom third party payment module for Magento 1.x to Magento 2.0.

However, when comes to redirecting the user to the third party payment gateway, the `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl` in my `Model\SomeName.php` doesn't seems like working. Some suggested that replacing some codes in the `/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/SomeName-method.js` for the redirect function.

Would like to clarify is it true that `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl` doesn't work in Magento 2.0. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/SomeName-method.js

   ```
   /*browser:true*/
   /*global define*/
   define(
        [
           'jquery',
           'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
           'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators'
       ],
       function ($, Component, additionalValidators) {
           'use strict';
           return Component.extend({
               defaults: {
                   template: 'Test_Payment/payment/default'
               },
               getInstructions: function () {
                   return window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions[this.item.method];
               },
               getPaymentIcon: function(){
                   return window.checkoutConfig.payment.icon[this.item.method];
               },
               afterPlaceOrder: function () {
                   $.mage.redirect('/test/checkout/redirect');
               },
           });
       }
   );
   ```
2. create controller\checkout\redirect.php

   ```
   public function execute()
   {
       try {
           $order = $this->_getCheckoutSession()->getLastRealOrder();

           $method = $order->getPayment()->getMethod();

           $methodInstance = $this->_paymentHelper->getMethodInstance($method);
           if ($methodInstance instanceof \Test\Payment\Model\Paymentmethod\Paymentmethod) {
               $redirectUrl = $methodInstance->startTransaction($order, $this->_url);
               $this->_redirect($redirectUrl);
           } else {
               throw new Error('Method is not a Test payment method');
           }

       } catch (\Exception $e) {
           $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong, please try again later'));
           $this->_logger->critical($e);
           $this->_getCheckoutSession()->restoreQuote();
           $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
       }
   }
   ```

Hope Help..

Comment: Not work then also use this ...http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94480/payment-module-redirect-to-payment-website-url-in-magento2

Comment: `/browser:true/ /global define/ define( [ 'jquery', 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default', 
...
Component.extend({ defaults: { template: 'Test_Payment/payment/default' }, getInstructions: function () { return window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions[this.item.method]; }, getPaymentIcon: function(){ return window.checkoutConfig.payment.icon[this.item.method]; }, afterPlaceOrder: function () { $.mage.redirect('/test/checkout/redirect'); }, }); } );` 
where do i place this? in the `/method-renderer/SomeName-method.js`?

Comment: yes. method-renderer/SomeName-method.js

Comment: hi i have encounter a new problem, feel free to have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319940/magento-2-redirecting-to-payment-gateway-error

Comment: delete var folder..then check,